# how can i create an event for a variable in a seperate (static) class

Tags: c#, asp.net

- I have a static class that holds the language of the user
- the site.master page has the button and code to set the language
- each page sets the labels according to language when each page loads

I need (i think) to have an event or property change event for when this variable in the static class changes so that i can call the child page function to re-write the labels according to the language.

my question is:
how can i have an event for a variable in a static class that calls a function that is not (and cannot be) in its static class

Comment: Having a static class with the language of the user sounds like a terrible idea as it would be shared across all users of your site.

Comment: oh, have i musunderstood ? i thought the static class would be per instance, ie. per load of the page, per user using it ?

Comment: in addition to the "single language" problem that @DavidG notes: you can't rewrite pages from the server; those responses have *gone*; you do *not* want to bind all your request objects to a static event - that would be terrible

Comment: @magiva you have indeed misunderstood; static fields on a type are once *per app-domain*, i.e. per server process instance; your server process handles *many, many* users, requests, etc

Comment: @magiva: It sounds like you have. An asp.net web server is a continuingly running application that receives and responds to requests. It does not start up a new "program" for each request or anything like that so a static class will be shared by the whole of this app and every request that comes into it from every user.

Comment: ok so this is a silly mistake on my part, can you suggest how i can create a session class for the person using it ?

Comment: yes i fully understand i well and truely messed up here, So.... my obvious question is what is the correct method to store session details of the user, if i instantiate the class, then it wouldnt be available if they moved pages... for example... i think i need to repost as a new question

Comment: @magiva you may be looking for ["session state"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx), although frankly: I think I'd just use a basic cookie for language...